# How can I get the file path after saved by nano editor?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, filepath, nano

I want to make a bash script that have to get the file path or file name after saved by nano editor for process. How can I get it?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I suspect it's not possible.

Comment: Please be more informative, or specific?

Comment: I just want bash script to echo the file path or file name after saved by nano.

Answer (score 1):

`man nano` doesn't show such option. You cany try to seek files created after specific date using `find`.

If you call nano with filename as parameter you could try: `history | grep nano | tail -n NUM` Where you could set NUM to number of last nano calls you want to see.